# Dynamically extend User entity in symfony

Tags: php, reflection, doctrine, symfony, traits

I have the following scenario:

- My project has an `AppBundle` with a `User` entity.
- Other bundles add more entities like `Address`, `Todo`, `Project`, `WhatEver`.
- Those entities must belong to a `User` so that I can call `$user->getAddresses()`, `$user->getTodos()`, `$user->addProject()`, `$user->setWhatEvers()`.
- Those bundles must remain "pluggable" so the `User` entity doesn't necessarily know about them and I can't add those properties like `todos` and its getters/setters directly into the `User` entity.

I thought about reflection, magic getters/setters, traits as possible aproaches but nothing really fits my needs.

I also considered *generating* the `User` entity but this would mean I have to regenerate it everytime I enable or disable a bundle and the database also has to be updated each time.

Maybe there is a completly different aproach?

Comment: are those entities ( Address, Todo, Project, WhatEver ) in one bundle or separated in a few bundles?

Comment: Maybe you can solve this with anyom classes  `new class extends User{}` if you run PHP7, that is then dynamiclly, if you dont want to extend for real.

Comment: If the dynamical part must only run once, you can create a console command which generates the full User entity, with the same logic as `doctrine:generate:entity` command.

Comment: @mmmm I will have an `AddressBundle` with entites like `Address`, `AddressCategory` and maybe a `ProjectBundle` which adds other entites related to that bundle. I don't know yet how many bundles and entites I will have. It is a quite big project and I definitly need this abstract way of altering users data.

Comment: Either add another bundle, that will have entity that extends User entity and will be aware of others bundle, or make the User in the AppBundle aware of those others entities. Every other solution will be a workaround and finally will become unreadable. Why would You even want to seperate it that much?

Comment: @mmmm Because I want external developers to be able to easily add bundles which add user fields, without altering the main User entity.

Comment: emm...repeat that sentence out loud and tell me how it sounds. "I want to make changes to the entity without making changes to the entity". Why developers can't make changes to User entity? What are You planing to store there in the end? For me it seems like problem is somewhere else, not in the User entity itself.

BTW - you can add magic methods - __set, __get and so on, but oh boy, wouldn't want to get into that project after few months.

Comment: @mmmm Maybe you are right and I just don't see some obvious point. It is all about a plugin system which can "tell a user" that he also can have this and that kind of objects now.

Comment: For me this is what AppBundle is for - it is aware of every thid-part library, focused on growing... app :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121181/discussion-between-markus-kottlander-and-mmmm).

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment so I have to answer. What about an Entity Key Value approach?

You can make a generic getter that filters an intermediate entity that keeps the relationship with third party Entities.

I personally don't like it as it can become quite difficult to maintain.

There is a bundle for tagging content that uses this approach. You can tag (relate) any entity (in this case your third party entities) with a tag (in your case the User entity)

Comment: could you further explain that or give an example or that bundle you talk about?

Comment: The bundle is fpn/tag-bundle. It creates an intermediate Entity called Tagging that saves the relationships with the Tag entity. Everything is managed by a TagManager service.

Comment: Not sure if this fits exactly in your needs but just in case...   [How to Define Relationships with Abstract Classes and Interfaces](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)